# Wrap a foreign API into a Ruby class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I use HTTParty to consume a foreign API, but how can I convert the response into a Ruby class or Rails model?

Comment: That depends on what the response is and what your class is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is going to depend on the output of your API. If the output is JSON, you can use the built-in Rails JSON parsing. If the output is XML in a Rails-friendly format, you may be able to use the built-in object-to-xml conversion tools. Otherwise, you may need to create your mapping explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If the response is XML [Nokogiri](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri) or [ROXML](http://github.com/Empact/roxml) come in handy. An alternative to ROXML would be [Happymapper](http://github.com/jnunemaker/happymapper).